# [Geometry]Prove that $AZ = 2ZC$

Tags: geometry

> Let $X$ be the midpoint of the side $AB$ of triangle $ABC$. Let Y be the midpoint of $CX$. Let $BY$ cut $AC$ at $Z$. Prove that $AZ = 2ZC$.

Please help me how to approach this problem... :?

My approach was:

Draw a line from $X$ parallel to $BC$ to meet $AC$ at $L$. Draw a line from $Y$ 
parallel to $XL$ to meet $AC$ at $M$.

Since $XL$ || $BC$ and $X$ is the mid point of $AB$.
therefore, L is the mid point of AC.

Similarly, $M$ is the mid point of $CL$.

Now, $AZ = AL + LZ$
$= LC + LZ$ (Since, $AL = LC$) 
$= LZ + ZC + LZ$ 
$= 2LZ + ZC$

I am not able to prove $2LZ = ZC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Draw the parallel to $BZ$ through $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line parallel to $XC$ from $B$ to the prolongation of  $AC$. Let's call that intersection point $I$. Then, $AXC$ and $ABI$ are similar, So if $XY=YC=k, BI=4k$.

Draw a parallel to $BZ$  from $C$ to $BI$. Let's call the intersection of those lines $J$. Since we have the parallelogram $BJCY$, $BJ=YC=k, JI=3k$.

If we let $BY=3m$, by the sme parallelogram we have $JC=3m$. So by similarity of $BIZ$ and $JIC$, $YZ=m$.

Draw a parallel to $BZ$ from $X$ to $AC$. call the intersection of both lines $P$. By similarity, $PZ=ZC$

Extend $CX$ $k$ units from $X$, and draw a line from the new endpoint called $Q$ to $A$. By similarity of $AQX$ and $BYX$, $AQ=BY=3m$. So by similarity of $AQC$ and $PXC$, $AP=PZ=ZC$.